# how to make a JSON response after create a resource successfully?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm building a Django-Tastypie server. After I create a resource successfully, the server will response me "201 created", but the Content-Type is `text/html`. I want the resource always return JSON response, how to do it?

Here's my resource code

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        resource_name = "user"
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

        allowed_methods=["post"]
        fields= ["username","email","id"]


    def determine_format(self, request):
        return "application/json"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
always_return_data = True
```

to your Meta.

And when you execute your `POST`, make sure that the url you are posting to has `?format=json` at the end. E.g.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/?format=json
```

Full example of a `POST` via curl:-

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"username":"calvin", "email":"myemail@myemail.com", "id": "1"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/user/?format=json
```